# Javascript sort array join two id

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to join the "ReplyID" and personality and sort them. Example "Reply ID" 16 data; "Id" under 16

```
dataPathRep.sort((a,b) => (b.ReplyIDId == a.ReplyIDId) ? (b.Id<a.Id):b.ReplyIDId < a.ReplyIDId)
```

OR

```
dataPathRep.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (nullif(a.ReplyIDId, "0") == "0") {
        return a.Id;
    } else if (nullif(a.ReplyIDId, "0") == "0") {
        return b.Id;
    } else if (b.ReplyIDId == a.ReplyIDId) {
        a.Id < b.Id;
    } else {
        a.ReplyIDId < b.ReplyIDId;
    }
});
```

[image]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: please add the code to the question, as well what you like to achieve.

Comment: @NinaScholz I added my code

Comment: Can you post an example of the data with before/after of what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: @MathewBerg My data http://i.hizliresim.com/4zMP8Y.png. I want to sort the "ReplyID" field based on the "Id" field. If "Id" is 16, then "ReplyId": I want the records to be placed under it. I tried to explain in the picture

Comment: Your sort function is wrong. It needs to return a number that is negative if they're the wrong way around, positive if they're the right way around. Here's some docs if you want to read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Rather than a picture full of arrows can you *please* just provide a sample dataset with expected and actual results.

Comment: maybe this:  a.Id < b.Id; will be return  a.Id < b.Id; or If a.Id < B.Id you must write other logic

Comment: Hi thank you for reply. Please view image. i told with image 
https://i.imgur.com/aEUcC9U.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a numerical value for [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

This can be achieved by using the delta of `ReplyIDId` and if the value is zero, hten the next delta of `Id` is taken.

For preventing `null` or `undefined` values, you could take a default value of zero.

```
dataPathRep.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.ReplyIDId || 0) - (b.ReplyIDId || 0)
        || a.Id - b.Id;
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you for reply. the code you suggested did not work. Please view image. i told with image https://i.imgur.com/aEUcC9U.png

Comment: @EnverKöseler, please add the data array for sorting (as text) and the dependency of the wanted order with the data.